# Make Image As Button With Link

Tags: java, android, android-studio

> in my .xml

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="@+id/imageView11"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/wa"
        tools:ignore="UsingOnClickInXml" />
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLYyr.png)

> How To Make This Image, to became Clickable and Redirect to some Url
> Thank You

Comment: As @BhoomikaPatel suggested, you can use `setOnClickListener` on it. Also, add the `android:clickable="true"` and `android:focusable="true"` attributes to the XML item

Answer (score 0):

You can manage it with `imageview.setOnClickListner` same like button's click listner.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share your link on whatsapp. Or share anything on whatsapp from your app then you can use this code to do.

First, add your ImageView to the ID. your id is `whatsappBtn`

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/whatsappBtn"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="@+id/imageView11"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/wa"
        tools:ignore="UsingOnClickInXml" />
```

and in your java code.

```
ImageView = whatsappBtn;
Uri yourUrl = yourLink // here your link

whatsappBtn = findViewById(R.id.whatsappBtn);

whatsappBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent goToWhatsapp = new Intent();
                        goToWhatsapp.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        goToWhatsapp.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                        goToWhatsapp.setType("text/plain");
                        goToWhatsapp.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,yourLink);//Extra text
                        context.this.startActivity(goToWhatsapp); //context = your activity Name
            }
        });
```

If you have still a confusion. let me know